# Loop through all UITextViews with certain tag number

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, for-loop, custom-cell

I have a bunch of `UITextFields` with the same tag number in a custom `UITableViewCell`. I'm trying to make a `for` loop that iterates through all the `textFields` with a certain tag number.

Here is my code:

```
for (UItextField *textField in [cell.contentView viewWithTag:8] {
    ... // Perform some code
}
```

When I do that, I get a warning at: `[cell.contentView view...]` saying:

```
Collection expression type 'UIView *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects.count'
```

What can I write instead of `[cell.contentView.view view...]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `viewWithTag:` it will return a single `UIView` object it doesn't work well with views with the same tag number. So it will return the first `UIVeiw`  it comes across with the tag `8` so what we want to be doing is looping through all the subviews held within that one view. Then check if it is a `UITextField` and the tag is equal to `8`. The reason for the `if statement` is that there is no guarantee that the object return in the loop will ever be a `UITextField`, even if we changed the object type from `id` to `UITextField` there is still no guarantee it will actually be a `UITextField` so we need to have the `if statement`.

```
// Retrieve all the subviews from contentView
for (id view in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
    // Check that the view is of UITextField and the tag is 8
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] 
            && [view tag] == 8) {
        // Assign to a UITextField object
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
        // Do whatever we want with that one field
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code: `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:8]` returns a single view, not an array, as specified in the documentation: [viewWithTag:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:)

If you want to get all the views that have the same tag one way would be using KVC:

```
NSArray *filteredViews = [containerView.subviews filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.tag == %d", 8]]
for (UIView *view in filteredViews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]) {
    //do something with the view
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually like this method it's not to bad +1

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UITextField *textfield in viewThatContainTheTextfields.subviews) {

         if (textfield.tag == 8) {

         }


}
```

Comment: There is no way of doing it without the if statement?

Comment: What's the problem with using `if`?

Comment: I'd rather just use a for loop without getting too messy with if statements, if that's possible?